# I want to compare 2 columns and mark the values that dont have a match

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables, these tables come from different applications and I would like access to compare 2 columns (the tag names) and point out to me wich tag names don't have a match

In the best case-scenario, there will be no names without a match, because both lists should be the same.

However, I would like access to check my tables, because I don't want to check 1000s of names myself.

Is it possible for access to mark or color the names that don't have a match?

If not, what would be the best way for me to distinguish the "unmatched" values?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The tables I'm using are called

```
DB_Total
```

and

```
TagNames_EA
```

In "DB_Total" I have 3 columns:

```
"Name"

"Address"

"Type"
```

In TagNames_EA

I only have the column

```
"Name"
```

The reason I want to compare these two is because I want a quick check to see if the values in EA are correct.

The code I am using is:

```
SELECT DB_Total.Address, DB_Total.Name, DB_Total.Type
FROM DB_Total LEFT JOIN TagNames_EA ON DB_Total.[Name] = TagNames_EA.[Name]
WHERE (((TagNames_EA.Name) Is Null));
```

This unfortunatly, only returns the rows that don't have a match.

I want access to mark the rows that don't have a match in my existing table. Is this possible?

Comment: You should include the schema information for the tables in your question.  Knowing that, someone might be able to give you an sql query that would answer your question.  If you can include some sample data as well.

Comment: You are missing a lot here: Table schemas, input values, expected output, actual output and the code you currently have.

Comment: I added most of the information available to me, I hope It's enough to make things clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My impression is you want to see all rows from *DB_Total* and include a calculated field which indicates whether a matching *Name* exists in *TagNames_EA*.

```
SELECT
    d.Address,
    d.Type,
    d.Name,
    IIf(t.Name Is Null, False, True) AS match_found
FROM
    DB_Total AS d
    LEFT JOIN TagNames_EA AS t
    ON d.Name = t.Name;
```

If you want to present those data with color to distinguish between matched and unmatched names, build a form based on that query and set a Conditional Format expression on *match_found*.

Answer (score 1):

The sense I get from reading your question is that you know DB_Total contains a correct list of Names, which can be used as a reference list. But TagNames_EA may or may not contain correct names. In other words, you want to see all Names from TagNames_EA which don't have a corresponding Name in DB_Total:

```
   select t.[Name] as TagNames_EA_Incorrect_Names
     from TagNames_EA as t
left join DB_Total as d
       on t.[Name] = d.[Name]
    where d.[Name] is null
```